# codesniffer not working with php 7.0 and netbeans 8.1

Tags: php, netbeans, phpcodesniffer

I have installed code sniffer with below steps ,

Download phpcs.phar file from below link
https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Go to NetBeans -> Tools -> plugins .
install PHPCSMD.

Now go to Tools -> options -> PHP, Find “Code Analysis”.
Put phar file path here.

Closed netbeans

open again netbeans.

right click on my project file and click on check for violation.

but it not gives me any result.

Comment: PHP 8.1? You mean 7.1?

Comment: yes it is my mistake in question title ,it is php 7.0 and netbeans 8.1

Comment: I have solved above problem ,I am using windows system,for windows system I have followed below url, http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42434/phpcsmd  and  
http://software.danielwatrous.com/php-codesniffer-and-mess-detecter-in-netbeans/